# Validating length of multiple languages

Tags: elixir, ecto, changeset

I am working on an multilingual app, which allows user to input multiple languages (eg, English, Chinese and Korean)

For registering user, I have `validate_length` function to validate length of first name and last name of user.

However, the problem I have is that I do not want same results for counting English letter and Chinese letter. For example, if I count length for "David" and "器防雷器防". Both of them return 5 even though Chinese characters take much more spaces.

Ecto currently supports counting length by `codepoints` and `graphemes` but either of them does what I need.

How can I do this? Is it even possible to count letter and validate by how much "bytes" does it take?

Comment: By "space" do you mean number of bytes? or visual size?

Comment: I mean visual size. But as Chinese characters from example has 10 more bytes than English characters, I guess using bytes will be fine.

Comment: If you mean Chinese is visually _wider_, it’s all about the font metrics and has nothing to do with Elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel.byte_size/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#byte_size/1):

```
iex(13)> byte_size("David")
5
iex(14)> byte_size("器防雷器防")
15
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to use a regex to match on Han and Hangul characters, and assign them a greater length:

```
> s = "David 器防雷器防 한글"
> r = ~r/\p{Han}|\p{Hangul}/u
> Enum.sum(for <<c::utf8 <- s>> do
     case Regex.match?(r, <<c::utf8>>) do
       true -> 2
       false -> 1
     end
   end)
21
```

This uses Unicode character properties, as described in [the `re` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#sect3).  Note the trailing `u` in the regular expression `~r/\p{Han}|\p{Hangul}/u`: it activates Unicode mode, which is required for this to work.